# Arduino HC-05 writes to serial monitor but not Bluetooth (Android)

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino

Greetings Stack Overflow community,

I am writing an android app that reads some data off of an HC05 bluetooth module.

I am just trying to read one byte but it just hangs there for a few minutes before it crashes. Maybe its a hardware problem, but perhaps there is some error in my code I do not see. If anybody has a clue as to why I would not be able to read from this module I would greatly appreciate the input.

Thanks!

```
for (BluetoothDevice iterator : bondedDevices) {
    if (iterator.getName().equals("HC-05")) {
        BluetoothDevice device = iterator;

        try { btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);} catch (IOException ex) {}
        try {btSocket.connect();} catch (IOException ex) {}

        if (btSocket.isConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to HC05", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //Write 'r' to arduino to tell it to send data.
            try {
                outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
                outStream.write('r');
            } catch (IOException ex) {}

            int byteCount = 1;
            byte[] rawBytes = new byte[byteCount];

            try {
                inputStream= btSocket.getInputStream();
                int a = inputStream.read(rawBytes, 0, 1);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a Bluetooth terminal app for android? This way you can find out if it's a hardware or software issue.

You could try this app:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=Qwerty.BluetoothTerminal